# django activate link/button if the path startes with `<path>`

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm building a Django app and I have a link on my navbar that I want to activate it(means add a css class) if the path starts with `<base_url>/accounts/`

I tried the following and it doesn't work

```
{% url 'accounts:profile' as pro %}
{% url 'accounts:setting' as set %}
{% url 'accounts:anotherpage' as ano %}

This doesn't work
{% if request.path == pro or request.path == set or request.path == ano %} active {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your ask:

```
{% if pro in request.path or set in request.path or ano in request.path %} active {% endif %}
```

but if you want

> I want to activate it if the path starts with <base_url>/accounts/

in this case:

```
{% if '/accounts/' in request.path %} active {% endif %}
```